# Problem sshpass using Runtime.getRuntime().exec on java, but on cmd tunning fine

Tags: java, ssh, cygwin, sshpass

can someone solve this problem? I using sshpass for transfer file on java. Execute this command

> Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sshpass","-p", "password","scp","-r",getContext().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/file/"+today)+"/ Name@myip:/cygdrive/d/file"});

and the error doesn't show on java using runtime.exec but on the command line running well.

my code

```java
try {

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"sshpass","-p", "password","scp","-r",getContext().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/file/"+today)+"/ Name@myip:/cygdrive/d/file"});

    // System.out.println(sshStr);
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    proc.getInputStream()));

    //--------------------check---------------------
    printStream(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");
    printStream(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
    //--------------------check---------------------

    try {
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    while (read.ready()) {
        System.out.println(read.readLine());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Runtime.exec(String)`, the string argument is split on whitespace, regardless of which quotes you've added. You have to use `Runtime.exec(String[])` instead. This leads to:

```java
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
        "sshpass",
        "-p", "password",
        "scp",
        "-r", getContext().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/file/" + today) + "/ Name@myip:/cygdrive/d/file"
    });
```

Comment: your code still no working for me @pieter12345

Comment: I see that you've updated your question following my suggestion. It's still possible that your path or any other argument is wrong as well. I can recommend trying to run it from cmdline and then put it in the code skeleton that I've provided to see if it works through Java as well. I have no clue whether your command is actually correct, I assumed that you had tested that already.

Comment: btw your code is working without using "Name@myip:", maybe because of used the symbol "@" or ":" that java exec can't read. do you know how to solve this?

Comment: @NisaAhmad When running the command directly from cmdline, does it work? And can you include that command in your question as well?